# Problems loading a module that have never occurred before

Tags: apache-2.2

So I just barely turned on my computer.

I opened up Chrome, and my home page, which is loaded off of my localhost server, came up with an error.

I went into terminal to manually start it, and it came up with:

```
Syntax error on line 22 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so\x16 into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so\x16, 10): image not found
```

I checked in the modules folder, and sure enough the module is still there. If I comment out the LoadModule line for mod_autoindex.so then everything (except the folder indexes) works fine.

Does anyone know what this means? Because apparently my guess was wrong.

This has never happened before and I haven't changed anything in httpd.conf in at least a week.

So confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is probably the `\x16` at the end of the filename. It is a non-printable control character which was probably introduced through some unwanted escaping in your editor.

Remove the character (or  remove the whole line and reenter it by hand) and everything should be fine.

Comment: I removed the newline and a few characters at the end, retyped them and now everything is happy again. :) I don't know how that character got there, or how it didn't cause problems sooner, but I'm glad it's gone. Thanks muchly.